# If function using google sheet script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a novice in google sheet script and I am trying to send a notification email to myself if a certain cell in a sheet is equal to 1. I have tried countless different approaches without success and would be grateful for help on this function. The function does not seem to be consistent in when to send the email, it seems as the If-function does not work. In my case, the D4 is a 1/0-variable.

My code looks as follows:

```
function myFunction(SHBA) {

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
      var range = sheet.getRange("D4")
      var dummy1 = range.getValue();
      if(dummy1 = 1){
          MailApp.sendEmail("rickard.bergqvist@tlk.nu", "SHB byt till A", "Spreadmodell"); 
        }
      }
```

Comment: The comparison operator is `==` NOT `=`(which is the assignment operator)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myFunction(SHBA) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
  var range=sheet.getRange("D4")
  var dummy1=range.getValue();
  if(dummy1 == 1){
    MailApp.sendEmail("rickard.bergqvist@tlk.nu", "SHB byt till A", "Spreadmodell"); 
  }
}
```